# Left Alt on External Keyboard Helper for use on JuiceSSH and Finch

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, external-keyboard

I like to use [JuiceSSH](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh) to connect a remote machine which is running [Finch](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Finch).
Finch uses <kbd>Alt</kbd> as its hotkeys prefix, for example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to go to the next window.

I have an external Bluetooth keyboard which has a left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and a right <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key. The <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key is working fine, my problem is with the left key. The only configuration I found in the **Custom Keymapping** is to put left <kbd>Alt</kbd> as left <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier. But that's not what I want, I don't want left <kbd>Alt</kbd> to be a modifier, I want the application to receive left <kbd>Alt</kbd> as it is, so that I can use shortcuts like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>, instead of getting the char **ñ**.

Basically, I want to be able to control Finch using the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> as the shortcut prefix.